# permission after getting adapter from bluetooth manager

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-permissions, android-bluetooth

I have an app where for some - but not all - features a bluetooth connection is required. Everything involving bluetooth communication works perfect.

However, when starting the app and if bluetooth is disabled on the phone, the user has to give permission to enable bluetooth - which is great. But, if I press "no", the app stops without any further comment. I have discovered that the permission dialog is called when invoking the .getAdapter() method:

```
final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
```

I want to give the user the possibility to press "no" and then for the app to continue, just without the bluetooth features. But since this is not a permission I ask programatically, I don't know where to intercept the permission anwser. Any ideas? I looked here but have not found the answer: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothManager#getAdapter()

Comment: "the app stops without any further comment" - are you sure there's no information in the logcat? Normally a crash is associated with some output.

Comment: No, there is nothing in the logcat. That's what made it so difficult, I didn't have a point where to start looking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to call

```
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
if(!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
     startActivityForResult(intent,1);
}
else {
     Toast.makeText(this,"Blurtooth Enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

After that `Blurtooth` `permission` dialog will pop up and the result of choice can be handled in `onActivityResult()`

```
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
               Toast.makeText(this,"Enable Enabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
           else
           {
               Toast.makeText(this,"Enable bluetooth first",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
   }
```